# ASP.NET Dashboard / Widgets

Tags: asp.net, widget, dashboard

I'd like to build a dashboard interface for an application I am working on. I want users to logon and get a birds eye view of the status of applications, outstanding issues, etc. I'm wondering if there are some good, pre-made controls rather than writing these from the ground up?

Comment: Hi Dave,

Did you manage to finally build a dashboard? I find myself currently in the same situation as you were in May 2010. My objective is to build an Ajaxy dashboard interface. Any ideas as to which language you used in the backend and which open source data visualisation libraries you used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at Telerik's [RadDock](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) control for ASP.NET AJAX. It is not free ;)

Answer (score 1):

For graphs and charts I would first try out the built in charting library in Visual Studio 2010.

If you cant use 2010 (even the express edition) for some reason then look at the charting controls for VS2008 [MS Charting](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for more of the ability to AJAXy create/control panels with information/charts/etc. inside of them...